# Wrapper .Net Framework to Core: System.Data.OracleClient

Tags: .net, .net-core, .net-standard, system.data.oracleclient

**Background**
I am currently facing the problem that my ASP.Net Core 5.0 Application is suddenly required to use a special library (from an external provider) for communicating with a database. Unfortunately, this library targets Framework 4.7.2.
An upgrade of the library to .Net Core/Standard is not realistic in the near future.
Therefore, my idea was to write a wrapper with the following structure: 
*Application Type*:     Worker Service   ↔   Standard library    ↔   Framework library
*Target Framework*:     .Net Core 5.0    ↔   .Net Standard 2.0   ↔   Framework 4.7.2
For test purposes, I used a Worker service instead of an ASP.Net web application. The Framework library references the said library, which is not available for .Net Core.

**Problem**
At first, I had the error:

> Could not load file or assembly
> 'System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager’

but I solved it by loading the NuGet package in the Standard library.
Now I run into the same Problem with another assembly:

> Could not load file or assembly 'System.Data.OracleClient,
> Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089'

Unfortunately, the **OracleClient** package is **deprecated** and no NuGet package is available for the Standard library. So, the solution from before is not valid anymore. 

**Attempted Solutions**
I tried to use Oracle.ManagedDataAccess but to no avail.
I think the chosen versions should be compatible but I have also tried this (in different combinations):

- Instead of   .Net 5                 →   .Net  3.1
- Instead of   .Net Standard 2.0      →   .NetStandard 2.1
- Instead of   .Net Framework 4.7.2   →   .Net Framework 4.6.1

**Questions**

1. Am I wrong about the versions of the targe frameworks being compatible?
2. I do not understand where exactly it is necessary to load the NuGet Packages. I thought it sufficient to reference them in the Framework library. But in case of the ConfigurationManager I had to reference the package in the Standard library.
3. Is there any way to use a Framework library which references System.Data.OracleClient in a .Net 5 application or a .Net Standard library?

I am close to giving up but then I would have to downgrade my Web App to Framework, which would require a lot of useless work.

Comment: About 2, in my experience, it depends on whether or not the library exposes types from the NuGet. If the library has a dependency, but no type form that dependency is exposed in its public API, then the code using the library should not need the dependency. However, if they are exposed, then the code using the library would not know how to handle those types, and would need to add the dependency too.

Comment: That is what I hoped for but in the Standard library I call only methods from the Framework library without parameters. There is no exposure. It compiles but produces the above error.